# What is the benefit of using a RichTextBox over a TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, richtextbox

After doing a bit of digging i found some (minor - in my opinion) added benefits in using a RichTextBox.  For instance, it is able to detect URLs.

What are the major benefits of using a RichTextBox over just using a TextBox?

Any input would be great.

FYI: (This is purely to help me make a better decision when programming as to which one i should use. Often i simply arbitrarily pick one. However, i want to make a more well thought-out decision)

Comment: What's the benefit of using Wordpad instead of Notepad?

Comment: When you need rich text, as opposed to simple text. The name seems clear enough... **Always** choose the `TextBox` unless you absolutely require the functionality of a `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, for example you can select a portion of the text and change its font, size, weight, etc in a RichTextBox. You can also insert inline images in an RTB. Just generally more advanced text-formatting capabilities than a normal textbox. Also, the TextBox has a 64k character limit, a limit that RTB is not affected by.

The text in a normal TextBox is just that, just text, without any additional data, with the only formatting being done with a combination of linebreaks, tabs and spaces, whereas the RichText-format has inline markup to allow for its advanced formatting capabilities. Of course, this comes at the price of larger files (proportional to the amount of markup you're using), and the fact that opening the file in an editor that can't parse RTF will result in the markup being visible.

For comparison, consider the Windows Notepad (TextBox) versus WordPad (RichTextBox).

Comment: +1 for the notepad(TextBox) - WordPad(RichTextBox) comparison.

Comment: Hmm okay, i see. Thanks, that comparison really helped put that into perspective. Guess i just have to play around with it a bit.

Comment: A truly nice answer. Very well explained. Upvoted this. Also thanks for comparing notepad and WordPad. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the "RTF" text and code (which includes font size, type etc.). E.g.:

```
                RichEdit.Rtf =
                "{\\rtf1\\ansi{\\fonttbl {\\f0 Sans Serif;}}" +
                "\\par\\qc\\fs40Complete" +
                "\\par\\ql\\fs20\\par Congratulations, completed!. To save these settings for future use, press 'Finish'.}";
```

This may help with the codes: [RTF codes](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod)